# How handle Fetch failures in Redux's action creators

Tags: reactjs, redux, isomorphic-fetch-api

Redux docs suggest to  have 3 different actions per AJAX request. For example for Login they would be:

- `LOGIN_REUQEST`
- `LOGIN_FAILURE`
- `LOGIN_SUCCESS`

But I have problem with catching all errors that can be thrown by `fetch`.
In redux docs I found this example:

```
return fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
  .then(
    response => response.json(),
    // Do not use catch, because that will also catch
    // any errors in the dispatch and resulting render,
    // causing an loop of 'Unexpected batch number' errors.
    // https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6895
    error => console.log('An error occured.', error)
  )
  .then(json =>
    // We can dispatch many times!
    // Here, we update the app state with the results of the API call.

    dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json))
  )
```

}

But I see several problems in it:

1. It doesn't use catch, so it wont catch any problems with AJAX request on user side (for example no internet)
2. It doesn't handle responses with status != 200.

I ended up this this code, but still it won't handle case #1 (because of React issue - see comment in above code):

```
 fetch('/api/auth/signin', {...}),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        }
    })
    .then ( response =>
        response.json().then(json => {
            if (response.ok) {
                dispatch(loginSuccess(json))
            } else {
                dispatch(loginFailure(json.errMsg))
            }
        })
     )
```

Can you please give me any example which handles all possible errors with AJAX request using fetch. Many tutorial and open-source projects just ignoring it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `.catch()` to handle offline errors. The second argument to `.then()`, the error callback, will catch offline (no internet connection) errors.

And, handling responses that are not 200 is straightforward:

```
fetch({...})
.then(
  response => {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      dispatch(loginFailed(response.json()));
      return Promise.reject();
    } else {
      return response.json();
    }
  },
  error => {
    dispatch(loginFailed(error.json()));
    return Promise.reject();
  }
)
.then(json => {
  dispatch(loginSuccess(json));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
async function fetchLists(url, token, userName, etag, dataToUpdate) {
var responseJSON;
try {
    let response = await fetch(url,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Access-Token': token,
                'X-Key': userName,
                'If-None-Match': etag
            }
        }
    );
    switch (response.status) {
        case 200:
            var data = await response.json();
            var dataType = getListForUpdate(dataToUpdate);
            responseJSON = {
                action: dataType,
                message: UPDATE_DATA,
                response: response,
                responseJSON: data
            }
            break;
        case 304:
            var dataType = getListUptoDate(dataToUpdate);
            responseJSON = { action: dataType, message: DATA_UPTO_DATE };
            break;
        case 404:
            responseJSON = { message: NOT_FOUND };
            break;
        case 500:
            responseJSON = { message: SERVER_ERROR };
            break;
        case 401:
        case 402:
            responseJSON = { message: INVALID_CREDENTIALS };
            break;
    }
    // console.log(response);
} catch (err) {
    // console.log(err);
    responseJSON = { message: NETWORK_REQUEST_FAILED };
    // console.log(responseJSON);
}

return responseJSON;
}
```

This code structure maybe able to solve your problem. I have recorded all the responses and left catch for network request failures. Comment if you don't understand any of it.

Hope it helps.